# Filling NaN rows with values from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe of 5 columns.

Three of those columns often have missing values (Only happens all together)

[image]

Now, I also have three "lists" of values I want to fill in for those na values for each columns.

a=[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]

b=[1,2,3]

c=[1,2,3]

.

Note that each list consists of only 3 values (since there are three rows of missing values per column). While the main table has 14 rows.

My first method was:

> df.where(df.notnull(), pd.Series(a), axis=0)

but this returned me a main table with two issues

[image]

1) filled all three columns with just list A value

2) It matched the rows of the main table and list A. Meaning that the main df filled first nan values(3rd row) with the 3rd value of list A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign to a sub-slice using `df.iloc`:

```
values = np.array([a, b, c])
idx = df.iloc[:, :3].isnull().all(0).index
df.iloc[idx, :3] = values
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following line
df.where(df.notnull(), pd.Series(a(0),b(0),c(0)), axis=0)